# RStudio Server C-Stack memory allocation setting in rsession.conf

Tags: memory, centos6, allocation, rstudio-server

I'm trying to increase C-stack size in rstudio server 0.99 on CentOS6 editing /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf file as follow:

rsession-stack-limit-mb=20

But "rstudio-server verify-installation" returns this message:

The option 'rsession-stack-limit-mb' is deprecated and will be discarded.

If I put this setting within /etc/rstudio/rsession.conf I obtain this message:

unrecognised option 'rsession-stack-limit-mb'

Someone can help me to find right configuration?

Thanks in advance

Diego

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use the free version of RStudio Server. According to https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/server/ServerOptions.cpp, it seems like you have to need a commercial version if you'd like to manage memory limits in RStudio Server.

Or, you can use "ulimit" command on CentOS, e.g., "ulimit -s 20000". Then, run R from the Linux command line or in batch mode.